# Structs with array member

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm studying structs and came across some misunderstanding. I wrote a couple of examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test{
    char field[16];
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    const char *string = "some string";
    struct test t1 = {.field = *string};
    struct test t2 = {.field = string};
    struct test t3 = {.field = "some string"};
    struct test t4 = {{'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'}};


    printf("t1::field = %s\n", t1.field); //prints s
    printf("t2::field = %s\n", t2.field); //prints garbage character
    printf("t3::field = %s\n", t3.field); //prints some string
    printf("t4::field = %s\n", t4.field); //prints some string
}
```

Output:

```
t1::field = s
t2::field = 4
t3::field = some string
t4::field = some string
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/FluwpD)

Another example is

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test{
    char field[16];
};

int main(void) {
    const char *string = {'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'};
    struct test t = {.field = *string};

    printf("t::field = %s\n", t.field); //segfault
}
```

Output is empty.

[ideone](https://ideone.com/f8We7C)

The behavior is not really clear to me. When allocating array memory we can take its n-th element as `arr[n]` which expands to `*(arr + n)`. So I expected that we initialized the `char field[16]` with some `char *` and it will be enough to treat an object pointed to by the pointer as the first element of some array.

But judging by the behavior my understanding was completely wrong. Can you please give a brief explanation of that?

Comment: A problem with ideone.com is that it doesn't show warnings by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> struct test{
>     char field[16];
> };
> ```

Contains a *character array* `field` with 16-char. An array can be either initialized or copied to, but *cannot be assigned*.

**Valid**

> ```
>     struct test t1 = {.field = *string};
> ```

(initialized `t1.field` to `string[0]` (e.g. `*(string + 0)` or just `*string`))

**Invalid**

> ```
>     struct test t2 = {.field = string};
> ```

(attempts to assign a **pointer** to *string literal* to array, see [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3))

**Valid**

> ```
>     struct test t3 = {.field = "some string"};
> ```

(uses *string literal* to initialize array)

**Valid**

> ```
>     struct test t4 = {{'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'}};
> ```

(`t4` is the same as `t3` except a *brace-enclosed* initializer is used and the *named-initializer* `.field` is omitted which dictates filling of members beginning with the first, see [C11 Standard § 6.7.9 Initialization (p19)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19))

Your *"Another Example"* fails for the same reason `t2` fails.

Comment: _initialized t1.field to string[0]_ Can you give some reference from the C11 Standard?

Comment: That will be `6.7.9(p19)` as well. You are initializing a single `char` in the array and all other elements not initialized are set to zero (*"initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration"* -- which is to zero).

Comment: The reference for initialization of object with *static storage duration* to zero is [6.7.9(p10)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10).

Comment: @SomeName i'm surprised too but you're allowed to omit braces for initializers of subaggregates and apparently using a designator doesn't change that

Comment: @M.M Are you sure? I tried to find a reference for that, but `initialezer` has the syntax `initializer: assignment-expression \n{ initializer-list } \n{ initializer-list , }`. So it seems if an `initializer` has braces omitted it is not really an initializer.

Comment: I'll have to dig, but in C, `{...}` is a *universal initializer*. If initializing to zero, it does not matter whether there are additional aggregate type (arrays, stucts, unions) within (default initialization). If, however, you are initializing the subaggregates to contain a value other than zero, then you will need to provide appropriate braces.

Comment: It is detailed in [6.7.9(p16-19)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p16) which must be read together for a complete picture of brace requirements. The use of `{0}` as the *Universal Initializer* is arrived at by *negative implication* (e.g. what is left over after all named and specific initializers requirements are omitted)

Comment: @SomeName `assignment-expression` is an initializer without braces

Comment: @M.M 148 footnote seems to be relevant. `148) If the initializer list for a subaggregate or contained union does not begin with a left brace, its
subobjects are initialized as usual[...]`. But what does this "as usual" mean? Btw are footnotes normative?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Actually, did not notice `the same as
objects that have static storage duration`...

Comment: Clarity of the Standard is "more of a goal, than the actual result." You serve yourself well by wading into the standard. Understand, that it doesn't try and answer every question, many times it contains what a compiler must provide to be "conforming", but leaves many details to the compiler writers to implement (becoming those loving "implementation defined" details). In 6.7.9, the writers try and cover initialization for just about every type and object allowed, including highly nested aggregate objects. Essentially, what results is a framework the compiler takes when parsing your code.

Comment: @SomeName "as usual" means as described in the normative text  (i.e. initializers are taken for each member of the subaggregate)

Answer (score 2):

In the first program `struct test t2 = {.field = string};` is an error because a pointer is not a valid initializer for a char array.

In the second program `const char *string = {'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'};` is an error because there cannot be more than 1 initializer for a pointer.

You should use a compiler which shows error messages for these errors, otherwise you are making learning C difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53773835/9658875) by David C.:

For whatever reason C had been designed to have (largely) the same syntax for declaration, definition and use of variables. This is an eternal source for confusion, and especially so with arrays.

Access to allocated memory can be achieved both using the array notation and the pointer notation; in fact the array notation gets 'decomposed' by the compiler to pointer notation.

This leads people to think that arrays are, in fact, pointers - but, from a source code perspective, they are not.

The two main differences are:

1) the initialization of both types is fundamentally different

2)

- a pointer is a variable in it's own right, has a distinct memory location where it 'lives', and therefore can be reassigned or otherwise manipulated.
- an array is more like a compiler directive. While memory is being allocated during its definition, there is no separate place where the address to that memory is stored. Instead, the compiler creates memory offsets against the stack (base) pointer in the machine code for any access into the array. When using something like arr_name or &arr_name[0], a temporary pointer is created (in some CPU register) which can be used for access into the array, or to be copied into a pointer variable, but in itself is not a separate entity. This is what people mean when they say "an array decays" into a pointer when used thus.

You might want to look at disassemblies of the use both of pointers and arrays; this [online tool](https://godbolt.org/) called godbolt is a very nice tool for that.

Comment: IDK why people have to give such complicated "explanations" of arrays . `int x[5]` is just 5 `int` objects next to each other. Nothing more and nothing less.  the concept of "place where the address to that memory is stored" is the same for array variables as for non-array variables.  None of this requires mentioning stacks or CPUs or compilers

Comment: @M.M If it was only about arrays, yes. However, the confusion comes from the similarities (source code level) between pointers to allocated memory and arrays.